# Function in [disabled] gets triggered before toggle change is registered

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app, I need to disable a button when there are no changes to a group. Each group consists of some locations and a boolean for `returnHome`. I also have the original set of locations and the original `returnHome` toggle setting. Here's how they're put together:

**Toggle slider HTML for returnHome:**

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="returnHome" (change)="onToggleReturnHome(returnHome)"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

**Button HTML:**

```
<button id="save-locations" mat-raised-button color="primary"
      [disabled]="hasGroupChanged()">
  Save Group
</button>
```

**Function that checks for change in Group:**

```
hasGroupChanged() {
  // To detect returnHome toggle change
  if(this.returnHome != this.originalReturnHome) {
    return true;
  }

  // Code to check if locations of the group have been changed
  // ...
}
```

Now, when I slide the toggle, I expect `returnHome` to be updated and once it goes into `hasGroupChanged()` through [disabled], it will check that `returnHome` is no longer same as `originalReturnHome` so it would return `true`, disabling the button.

But when I put breakpoints on the `onToggleReturnHome()` and `hasGroupChanged()`, as soon as I click on it, `hasGroupChanged()` occurs first and doesn't recognize that the `returnHome` was updated. As a result, the button never gets enabled from toggling.

How can I make sure that `onToggleReturnHome()` gets triggered first before `hasGroupChanged()` does? Is this even possible given Angular execution flow? If not, how could I make sure that the button can get disabled/enabled properly?

Comment: Without delving too deep, there is a cheap fix - in order to miss the first hook that fires before the returnHome has changed, you could add an rxjs operator like `of(1, asyncScheduler).subscribe(x => {  if(this.returnHome != ... });`. This skips a whole round of hooks, allowing returnHome to update first.

Comment: what is doing `onToggleReturnHome` function? if possible can you please put this function code as well?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are changing `returnHome` property value two times?  one by `ngModel` and second from `onToggleReturnHome` function?

Answer (score 0):

first of all , don't hook your attributes to functions unless you really have to , because that will re-render even when there aren't any changes , you can hook it to a variable in your component and the changes will be picked up by angular (default behavior),  can you provide the function "onToggleReturnHome" ?

Comment: I agree with this advice. Although I disagree with answers telling people what not to do instead of just solving their problem for them. I admire the investment in their learning process though ;)